# Password less login while running bash script without public key authentication

Tags: linux, shell-script, password

I need to run a some command through bash script  on some storage devices which do not support public key based authentication. So is there any other way i can run script on these devices without entering the password manually.
I have username and password and it is same across all devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual answer for this type of problem is to use https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect.

Comment: Thanks icarus let me explore it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [sshpass](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) utility. It’s a bit easier to use than expect (and doesn’t have all the gross TCL dependencies) (I speak as a former TCL programmer).

Comment: thanks jsbillings let me explore it.

Comment: There are implementations of expect in other languages such as perl (Expect.PM) and python (pexpect) if TCL is one step too far.